# How to add buttons in a WPF Ribbon without moving all the next controls?

Tags: wpf, button, position, ribbon

I use a WPF Ribbon like this:

```
<Ribbon x:Name="RibbonWin"  SelectedIndex="0">
...
<RibbonTab Name="OpenShow" Header="Open/Kijk" KeyTip="O" >

<TextBox x:Name="X" Width="300">
<RibbonButton x:Name="LangNL" SmallImageSource="Images\FLGNETH.ico" Label="NL"/>
<RibbonButton x:Name="LangEN" SmallImageSource="Images\FLGUK.ico" Label="EN"/>
<RibbonButton x:Name="Nextlotbutton" SmallImageSource="Images\go.png" Label="Open"/>
```

As you can see in the picture this shows a TextBox and 2 buttons (country flags) with a label under it.Then the next 3 buttons are displayed in the next column (only the first one is in the WPF code snippet).

I want a small picture button in front of the TextBox and/or some more buttons left of flag buttons and below the TextBox; just in this picture I added some grey buttons as an example where I want these.

This seems impossible. Even when I add button and position it to the the required position using Margin, the next button in the  same "row" as the TextBox will move down 1 position and the original position is empty. It works like a StackPanel, add an element and everything below this in the WPF moves one position down and to the right, regardless the actual position defined with Margin.

Is there anything I can do to circumvent that behavior?[image: How to use the area where the arrow is placed]

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you can do that directly in a `Ribbon`, but you can try to replicate the layout using the [`RibbonControlGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrolgroup?view=net-5.0) control. It will display the child controls horizontally. However, its style for the text box and buttons controls is  a little bit different than in a normal ribbon group and will behave differently.

```
<Ribbon>
   <RibbonTab Header="Tab">
      <RibbonGroup Header="Group">
         <RibbonControlGroup>
            <RibbonButton Label="TB"></RibbonButton>
            <RibbonTextBox/>
         </RibbonControlGroup>
         <RibbonControlGroup>
            <RibbonButton Label="NL"></RibbonButton>
            <RibbonButton Label="NL 1"></RibbonButton>
            <RibbonButton Label="NL 2"></RibbonButton>
         </RibbonControlGroup>
         <RibbonControlGroup>
            <RibbonButton Label="EN"></RibbonButton>
            <RibbonButton Label="EN 1"></RibbonButton>
            <RibbonButton Label="EN 2"></RibbonButton>
         </RibbonControlGroup>
      </RibbonGroup>
   </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

Since the buttons are stacked horizontally, you might assign widths explicitly or add margins and paddings to achieve the desired layout. The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for this info! I was unaware of the existence of the RibbonControlGroup. I actually finally did solve with a trick; as I wanted to add exactly 3 buttons I managed to move these to appropriate positions without harming the rest of the positions but I am sure your solution will work much better with less or more than what fits in a specific Ribbon (3 on mine).

This I added (the main part of the XAML code):

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="GoParent" SmallImageSource="Images\up.png" Click="GoParentDir" Margin="-320,0,310,0"  />
<RibbonButton x:Name="GoDone" SmallImageSource="Images\right.png" Click="GoDoneDir" Margin="-280,0,200,0"  />
<RibbonButton x:Name="GoGPS" SmallImageSource="Images\right.png" Click="GoGPSDir" Margin="-280,0,200,0"  />
```

And this is the result (the 3 buttons with the black arrows)

[image: After adding 3 buttons using Margin]

Dick